# nvim coc.nvim: Error detected while processing BufNewFile Autocommands for "*" when open ptrhon files

Tags: lua, neovim

here are the errors, this problem only occurs when opening Python files
i am using coc.nvim to complete the code
idk what course this problem
any ideas will be appreciated

```
Error detected while processing BufNewFile Autocommands for "*":
Error executing lua callback: /usr/share/nvim/runtime/filetype.lua:22: Error executing lua: /usr/share/nvim/runtime/filetype.lua:23: Vim(for):E715: Dictionary required
stack traceback:
        [C]: in function 'nvim_cmd'
        /usr/share/nvim/runtime/filetype.lua:23: in function </usr/share/nvim/runtime/filetype.lua:22>
        [C]: in function 'nvim_buf_call'
        /usr/share/nvim/runtime/filetype.lua:22: in function </usr/share/nvim/runtime/filetype.lua:11>

stack traceback:
        [C]: in function 'nvim_buf_call'
        /usr/share/nvim/runtime/filetype.lua:22: in function </usr/share/nvim/runtime/filetype.lua:11>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should declare the ale_linters. I faced the same error for Python and hence I realized my old configuration was like `vim.g.ale_linters = {}`

```lua
50  vim.g.ale_linters = {
  1     ['*'] = {'ale_linters'},
  2     ['python'] = {'flake8'},
  3     ['sh'] = {'shellcheck'},
  4     ['zsh'] = {'shellcheck'},
  5     ['vim'] = {'vint'},
  6     ['lua'] = {'luacheck'},
  7     ['go'] = {'golangci-lint'},
  8     ['dockerfile'] = {'dockerfile_lint'},
  9 }
```